# How to share iPad's wifi to Mac?

Tags: ipad, mac, wifi, internet-sharing, tethering

I want to connect my MacBook Pro to my iPad mini's Wi-fi. I don't see any hotspot settings. I have searched on the web but all I see is to go to cellular option in setting which is not available in my iPad (cause there is no SIM).

Can this be achieved through Bluetooth sharing, a personal hotspot, USB tethering or any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iPad mini and the MacBook Pro is on the same WiFi, they also have the same IP-adr. range, so they can see each other.

The Personal Hotspot option is for sharing an internet connection, and here you have the cellular network (SIM-card) as the external connector, and the WiFi (Personal Hotspot) as the DHCP Server.

Comment: Only my ipad is connected to wifi. The wifi isn't available to mac. I want my mac to use ipad's wifi.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it isn't possible. You need two WiFi cards on the iPad if it should work, and you don't have this.

Comment: But it is possible if i use a android phone by usb tethering. Cant it be possible on Mac somehow, may be by means of some external software?

Answer (score 0):

The Personal Hotspot option is only available to devices that use a SIM card with cellular data. A device connected to a wi-fi cannot share that connection to another device, you have no other choice but to get that other device within the range of the same wi-fi router.

Comment: But it is possible in case of android by usb tethering. Cant it be possible on Mac somehow, may be by means of some external software?

Comment: @Kitty The USB tethering option for Apple devices is only available for devices that have cellular data connection OR jailbroken devices. I don't jailbreak mine so I am not sure how it works.